# Tool for rendering/drawing maps from coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon

What tools can be used to convert a set of coordinates into polygons?

For example: this code represents a room by providing information about it's four corners.

```
<node id='-202' lat='41.015146' lon='6.092984' /> 
<node id='-200' lat='41.015146' lon='-6.092817' />
<node id='-198' lat='41.015075' lon='-6.092977' />
<node id='-196' lat='41.015090' lon='-6.092806' />

<way id='-266' type='room'>
    <nd ref='-202' />
    <nd ref='-200 />
    <nd ref='-198' />
    <nd ref='-196' />
 </way>
```

What I want to do is read that information and draw the respective room. Making possible that way to have an indoor map.

[image]

This screenshot shows the kind of result that I'm trying to achieve. Where the outline of the  rooms of a building was converted into a well designed map, unfortunately that [app](http://support.sailstech.com/kb/tutorial/step3-render-your-indoor-map-by-sails-mre-map-render-editor) is for android only.

In this community the feature "Delimited Text Layer" of QGIS has also been suggested. Is there any other tools to perform this kind of task?

Answer (score 1):

The mmqgis plugin is a bit more comfortable than the delimited text import.

You can read from csv, and choose whether the result should be points, lines or polygons.

---

**EDIT**

The source data you now added to your question looks pretty much like Openstreetmap format.

So you can add it using `Add Vector Layer` or the Openstreetmap plugin, part 2 and 3. Part 1 - download - is not necessary if you already have it on disk.

Comment: I would also suggest using the available OSM data import tools.

Comment: I have tried the Openstreetmap plugin just like you said before posting this question. Since QGIS don't recognize the tags that I've used for the indoors rooms, the only thing drew was the "main" building. I guess my problem now is to find a way to convert that OSM data into something that QGIS can understand.

Comment: The OSM plugin can read all key-value entries if you click on `read from database`. The `type="room"` attribute you gave is not compatible to the key-value scheme, hence it is ignored. You might try `<tag k="type" v="room" />` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As well as mmqgis (`mmqgis->Import/Export->Geometry Import from CSV`) that Andre mentions, if you have the points data in QGIS already (possibly via the delimited text import), then you can use Points2One plugin to assemble them into polygons.  You can also do it in SAGA but would need a two step process (points->lines->polygons).

As ever, you can also script a solution using (say) Python and GDAL, which is the way I'd go if I had a LOT of files and needed a batch processes.  For one or two lots, I'd just use a plugin.

The important thing, whatever method, is that you have a polygon ID field as well as the coordinates.  This is what all the methods use to know how to assemble the points into their respective polygons.  If you don't have that, then you need to import your points as points, make the layer editable (which if it is a csv layer will involve saving it as a shapefile or similar).  You can now add the polygon id to the attribute table and then iterativly select and tag groups of points with a suitable polygon id. Once all points have a polygon id, you will be ready to assemble them into a polygon.

Comment: The first try with Points2One wasn't perfect, but with a little more work I think it can work.